# When does a sum of orthogonal projectors converge?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $\{U_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of closed subspaces of $H$. Are there any sufficient or neccessary criteria for the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty P_{U_k}$ to converge (in norm or pointwise)? If the subspaces $\{U_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ are orthogonal to each other, then it is clear, but are there any other criteria (maybe $\omega$-linear indepencendy)?

Comment: It will converge in norm iff it is a finite sum. Pointwise you have much more freedom, though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $\omega$-independence, but it is not sufficient, e,.g., $U_n=\langle e_1+n^{-n}e_n\rangle$, and it is not necessary because you could modify finitely many $U_k$.

Comment: @user10354138 $\{U_k\}_k$ is $\omega$-linear independent iff from $\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i = 0, u_k \in U_k$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty ||u_i||^2 < \infty$ it follows that $u_i = 0$ for all $i = 1,2,...$